# To reduce the quality of the image to be displayed in the VF Page

Tags: images

I am developing  page with 15 images each of 500kb-1Mb. It causes the page to load very slow. Is there any way to reduce the Image Quality of the Image in Salesforce Automatically while displaying the Images?? I tried to reduce the image to specific Height and Width Dimension. Still the proble persist!

Comment: Probably it makes some sense to prepare 2 set of images and use async loading to load small one first, and so soon as bigger one is ready -- replace URL for it. for example -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999760/load-image-asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever you upload eventually has to be downloaded again. If you're uploading 1MB images, the entire 1MB image has to be downloaded to the browser before it can be displayed. Setting the height/width would have no effect, as the entire file still has to be downloaded from the server before the image can be shrunk down. Possible solutions include [Responsive Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images), [Progressive Image Loading](https://github.com/craigbuckler/progressive-image.js), or just plain uploading smaller files. If these are user-selected files, you can use an [HTML Canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223466) to reduce the image size/quality to a reasonable level before uploading.